# Is it possible to pause in WatiN?

Tags: c#, watin

My WatiN application automates through several webpages.

Is it possible for the automation to pause at a certain point, and to only continue the automation when the user says so (clicks a Continue button)?

Comment: What are you using - WinForms, WPF? Take a look at events - for example this one http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar in my project, maybe this can help (I've not properly tested this, but it might point you in the right direction :D)

```
private System.Threading.AutoResetEvent arEvent = null;
private System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon nIcon = null;

public void WatinBreakpoint()
{
    this.arEvent = new System.Threading.AutoResetEvent(false);
    this.nIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    this.nIcon.Text = "Watin Breakpoint.  Double click to continue";
    this.notifyIcon.DoubleClick += new EventHandler(notifyIcon_DoubleClick);
    this.arEvent.WaitOne();
}

private void notifyIcon_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.arEvent.Set();
}
```

HTH!